# How can I debug $Model after validation?

Tags: validation, cakephp, model, callback

I want to see the content of validationErrors => array(???) of the $Model after a failed validation, but there is no "afterValidation()" method. 
Does anyone know how can I see that or at least how would it look exactely?

Thank's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Controller, you can validate data before you trying save:

```
$this->ModelName->set($this->request->data);

if ($this->ModelName->validates()) {
    // success
} else {
    // failed
    $errors = $this->ModelName->validationErrors;
}
```

Reference:

- [Validating Data from the Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->ModelName->invalidFields()` after you have made the save/whatever you're doing:

For example:

`debug($this->ModelName->invalidFields());`

If you have a redirect at some point after that call, you might not see the data in your view. In this case, you can always do `die();` either right after or wrapped around your call like so:

`die(debug($this->ModelName->invalidFields());`